# CSV nominal values' wrong recognition in R

Tags: r, excel, ms-access, csv

I have numbers declared as a text (a.k.a. nominal) in MS Access. These numbers represent simplified versions of what could have been long sentences as categories.

I currently tried exporting the file as `csv` in three ways:

1. MS Access' native `csv` function
2. MS Excel's native `csv` function (from MS Access)
3. LibreOffice Calc's "Use Text CSV Format"; I even check the "Quote all text cells" option to ensure that all nominal values are taken care of.

The problem is in R when I try using `summary(data)` and see that these number-nominal values are still interpreted as numeric even though the values are enclosed in double or single quotation marks. I am sure of it since I saw these variables given (in the `summary` function) the mean, median, and others compared to the ones with characters that are shown with frequencies.

In the example below, both `var1` and `var2` are nominal wherein the latter is represented by numbers (note that the values of `var2` results are changed for security).

```
var1            var2
Cat  : 111   Min.   :1   
Dog  : 222   1st Qu.:1   
Bee  : 333   Median :8   
Yog  : 555   Mean   :10   
Fig  : 999   3rd Qu.:1
Kol  : 444   Max.   :15                                      
(Other):2250
```

I've thought of appending a character to these number-nominal values (instead of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, I'll have `1a, 2a, 3a, 4a, 5a`) to ensure that these are interpreted as nominal but I am hoping for a new solution here before going to that arduous task.

Comment: You should probably use `colClasses` when reading the data into R and set it to "character" for all the relevant columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read.table` and family have a `colClasses` argument.

See the following examples to see the difference in the results when using different `colClasses`:

#### Sample data

```
text <- c("A,B,C", "1,2,3", "2,1,4")
```

#### Default `read.csv`

```
A <- read.csv(text = text)
str(A)
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ A: int  1 2
#  $ B: int  2 1
#  $ C: int  3 4
summary(A)
#       A              B              C       
# Min.   :1.00   Min.   :1.00   Min.   :3.00  
# 1st Qu.:1.25   1st Qu.:1.25   1st Qu.:3.25  
# Median :1.50   Median :1.50   Median :3.50  
# Mean   :1.50   Mean   :1.50   Mean   :3.50  
# 3rd Qu.:1.75   3rd Qu.:1.75   3rd Qu.:3.75  
# Max.   :2.00   Max.   :2.00   Max.   :4.00
```

#### Read data in as `character`

```
B <- read.csv(text = text, colClasses = "character")
str(B)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ A: chr  "1" "2"
#  $ B: chr  "2" "1"
#  $ C: chr  "3" "4"
summary(B)
#     A                  B                  C            
# Length:2           Length:2           Length:2          
# Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
# Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character
```

#### Read data in as `factor`

```
C <- read.csv(text = text, colClasses = "factor")
str(C)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ A: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2
#  $ B: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 1
#  $ C: Factor w/ 2 levels "3","4": 1 2
summary(C)
#   A     B     C    
# 1:1   1:1   3:1  
# 2:1   2:1   4:1
```

---

The `colClasses` argument accepts a `vector`, so you can specify on a column-by-column basis what the values should be:

```
D <- read.csv(text = text1, colClasses = c("integer", "character", "factor"))

str(D)
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ A: int  1 2
#  $ B: chr  "2" "1"
#  $ C: Factor w/ 2 levels "3","4": 1 2
summary(D)
#        A             B             C    
#  Min.   :1.00   Length:2           3:1  
#  1st Qu.:1.25   Class :character   4:1  
#  Median :1.50   Mode  :character        
#  Mean   :1.50                           
#  3rd Qu.:1.75                           
#  Max.   :2.00
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the `factor` that I wanted.